# Ability to run branching SCORM packages on Blackboard

Tags: scorm, blackboard

I'm new in SCORM and don't know a lot about it.

My customer already has his own custom LMS with courses. And he wants these courses "to be mounted on Blackboard". And it appears that material would have to be SCORM compliant to play in Blackboard.

The problem is, that existing courses are not linear, but branching. For example, if user answered "Yes" on first question, he will get question with id=2 next. If he answered "No", he will get question with id=3 next. **As I understood, you do not have the ability to create such "branching" packages in SCORM. Only linear. Am I wrong?**

Or, maybe, Blackboard allows you to use your own LMS and only send back to Blackboard "SCORM big four" data?

Answer (score 1):

When I last checked Blackboard Learn included the same SCORM player used by scorm.com.  So if the packages play there they should work within Blackboard Learn. You might be better off implementing the courses in Blackboard's internal content structure.

Answer (score 0):

SCORM 2004 would allow you to take advantage of the sequence and navigation.  Enabling you to set pre/post rules on skipping based on outcomes.  Allows for controlling the flow, choice and allowing the student to move forwards and backwards (or not).  You'll have to see if it fits the use case though.

IMS Simple Sequencing was dropped into it, so most the detail I think you'll find more beneficial from IMS Global since for whatever reason it's not highly documented in the SCORM 2004 specification. http://www.imsglobal.org/simplesequencing/

There are also a lot of moving parts here to so it can get overwhelming.  I can't say I've ever seen a great tool to design this flow/rule/behavior, and its been the subject of a few reasons why some feel SCORM 2004 didn't get more widely adopted.  SCO's can make requests to the "adl.nav" space for requesting jumping to another SCO or continuing etc. too.

Rustici has some "Golf Examples" on http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/ which also highlight some of these more rich examples under the "SCORM 2004 4th Edition" section on that page.  But have several SCO and manifest examples you can use as a basis for understanding a little of what you can accomplish.

Edit: Another option if its just single questions, is to just let a SCO manage this.  I've had this on ones where they had "roles" at the beginning and we had to present different questions to a counselor vs. a teacher.  So you can have more custom control within the SCO, and you don't have to get your geek on with all the IMSManifest.xml rules.

Thanks and good luck,
Mark